# How to render to a MTLTexture using CoreGraphics

Tags: svg, core-graphics, scenekit, metal, metalkit

How can I render the content of a CoreGraphics context into a MTLTexture with full color and transparency? (RGBA or BGRA)

I am planning to use that MTLTexture for a material in a cross platform (macos/iOS) SceneKit project.

This example uses grayscale only:

https://medium.com/@s1ddok/combine-the-power-of-coregraphics-and-metal-by-sharing-resource-memory-eabb4c1be615

In the image the black background should be transparent. The right side (RGB) looks like misaligned. The texture only shows on iOS, doesn't work on macOS.

[image: The black backround should be transparent]

Update (What I attempted):

```
//        First, we will need to know a RAM page size from the system, for this reason we will use getpagesize() function. Now we have to calculate amount of aligned bytes per row and the total allocation size. To allocate aligned memory we will use posix_memalign(_,_,_) system function.


        let width = Int(256)
        let height = Int(256)


        #if os(macOS)
            let pixelRowAlignment = Int(1024)
            let bytesPerRow = alignUp(size: width, align: pixelRowAlignment)
        #else
            let pixelRowAlignment =
                sceneRenderer.device?.minimumTextureBufferAlignment(for: .rgba8Unorm)
            let bytesPerRow = alignUp(size: width, align: pixelRowAlignment!) * 4
        #endif




        let pagesize = Int(getpagesize())
        let allocationSize = alignUp(size: bytesPerRow * height, align: pagesize)

        //Allocate the memory pointed by data:
        var data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil
        let result = posix_memalign(&data, pagesize, allocationSize)
        if result != noErr {
            fatalError("Error during memory allocation")
        }



//        Now we are ready to create a CGContext from this memory, you probably have done this many times, so this should be pretty straightforward:

        //Gray (ok!)
        let context = CGContext(data: data,
                                width: width,
                                height: height,
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue)!

        //RGB (Weird)

//        let context = CGContext(data: data,
//                                width: width,
//                                height: height,
//                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
//                                bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
//                                space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
//                                bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!


        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: -CGFloat(context.height))
        context.setLineJoin(.round)
        context.setLineWidth(10)

        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.setLineJoin(.round)

        context.setStrokeColor(SCNColor(rgb: 0xFFFF00).cgColor)



        context.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        context.setFillColor(SCNColor.clear.cgColor)
        context.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
        context.strokePath()


//        Using the exact same memory we can now create a no-copy MTLBuffer, making it responsible for deallocating the memory. However you can of course manage this on your own by passing nil to the last argument.

        #if os(macOS)


        let buffer = sceneRenderer.device?
            .makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy: context.data!,
                        length: allocationSize,
                        options: .storageModeManaged,
                        deallocator: { pointer, length in free(data) })!

        #else
        let buffer = sceneRenderer.device?
            .makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy: context.data!,
                        length: allocationSize,
                        options: .storageModeShared,
                        deallocator: { pointer, length in free(data) })!
        #endif



//        Now, the final step: we are creating a texture from this buffer. Storage mode of the texture must be the same with the buffer.


        let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
        textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .r8Unorm
        textureDescriptor.width = context.width
        textureDescriptor.height = context.height
        textureDescriptor.storageMode = (buffer?.storageMode)!
        // we are only going to read from this texture on GPU side
        textureDescriptor.usage = .shaderRead

        let texture : MTLTexture = (buffer?.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor,
                                                        offset: 0,
                                                        bytesPerRow: context.bytesPerRow))!




//        You should take into account the memory synchronization that happens between CPU and GPU. You should not create a situation where this buffer can be simultaneously accessed by CoreGraphics and Metal, especially on macOS.



        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 1.0 , height: 1.0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant
        material.isDoubleSided = false


                            //Assign the previous MTLTexture to the maaterial

        material.diffuse.contents = texture



        material.blendMode = .alpha

        plane.firstMaterial = material

        let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        node.simdPosition = float3(0,0,0)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Modifying that code to draw to an RGBA texture instead should be fairly straightforward, so if you give us an idea of where exactly you're having trouble, we'll be able to provide more specific help.

Comment: @warrenm, updated. When I change the settings to RGB the texture looks misaligned. What I want to achieve is: whatever path I draw in a core graphics context to be mirrored on a MTLTexture.

Comment: When happens when you set the pixel format of the texture to `.rgba8unorm`?

Comment: Wha!!! didn't see that!!! It's working now on iOS! (but on macOS the texture doesn't even shows up, I think is something related to the buffer .storageModeManaged)

Comment: Yes, on macOS you'll need to use a blit command encoder to synchronize the contents from the GPU to the CPU as detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/synchronizing_a_managed_resource).

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work on my MacBook. Does the shared storage mode not work on macOS? That article uses it. I'm wondering how you knew to switch to managed storage mode. His sample code worked (after a tweak related to alignment), but it was running in Mac Catalyst mode, so maybe that's different.